# Outlook shows save confirmation dialog (message lose digital signature in case of saving) in Application.ItemSend event handler

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mapi

I'm developing Outlook VSTO add-in that checks Outlook.MailItem attachments. As far as I need to get access to internals of OLE and .msg file (embedded)attachments, I use glue with C++ Extended MAPI.
I received digitally signed message and when I'm trying to reply the save confirmation dialog is showing (with caption - "...If the changes are saved, the message will lose its digital signature.").
This behavior repeats only when I'm trying to make reply for digitally signed message. In the code below add-in call Save() for Outlook.MailItem (saves it into Drafts folder by default
and after that MailItem obtains EntryID), set Cancel=true and make some long work with attachments in another thread and if the work result is ok, add-in call MailItem.Send() programmatically.
Obviously this dialog shows when mailItem.Save() was called. But without mailItem.Save() call, I can't to obtain attachment type (PR_ATTACH_METHOD through GetProps or HrGetOneProp return NO_ATTACHMENT) in C++ part.

```
    private void ApplicationItemSendHandler(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
        bool errorCaused = false;

        try
        {
            mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem == null)
                return;

            if (mailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
                return;
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.EntryID))
                mailItem.Save();
                
            Cancel = true;
            
            //make some long work with attachments.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorCaused = true;
            Logger.Debug($"Error occured during call {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}: {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (errorCaused && mailItem != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailItem);
        }
    }
```

My question - how to suppress or get around this dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead do the processing in the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder - the message will be saved at that point.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for advice. I've tried some with Items.ItemAdd - message was successfully sended, but according my app logic add-in shouldn't send a message if attachments check (long work) was failed (message must stuck in Outbox or another folder). For example I added custom user properties for mailItem in ItemSend handler (process repeated send() call from code), set first Cancel=true, move long work to ItemAdd, but it doesn't work. If first Cancel=false - message was sended, If Cancel=true - ItemAdd didn't fired.

Comment: If you can access Attachment,Type in the ItemSend event handler using OOM, no need for Extended MAPI and C++

Comment: I tried to get binary data of attachment (olByValue type) that doesn't saved through PropertyAccessor.GetProperty with PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN property tag and got error. Also I need to get internals of OLE and .msg attachments through PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ. As far as I know VSTO doesn't support this functionality that's why I used C++ MAPI.

Comment: Let's step back a bit - the prompt is shown when the original item is modified to have its icon and last verb etc. updated, right? Do you see the problem if the user explicitly saves the item (Ctrl+S) before hitting Send?

Comment: I created reply for message with digital signature and pressed Ctrl+S without pressing Send button. Promt dialog didn't shown. May be Is it OOM bug or Outlook do something with MailItem before save (set some properties, etc.)?!